# Обработка нажатия F1

Tags: java

как можно отловить нажатие F1? 
сейчас сделано вот так, но с функциональными клавишами это не работает

```
root.setOnKeyTyped(ke -> {
        if (ke.getCharacter().equals("?"))
                System.out.println("f1");
                //тут должен быть запуск справки
    });
```

Видела информацию про виртуальне кнопки VK_F1, но идея вообще не понимает, чего я от нее хочу, подчеркивает красным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F1) {
       System.out.println("f1");
     }
```

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_F1)
 [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18037609/5330439)

**update**

Помогло так

```
if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.F1)) {...
```

*Справка*

`VK_F1` [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_F1), `F1` [KeyCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#F1)

Comment: пробовала, getKeyCode() метода вообще не видит (только getCode()), и VK_F1 подчеркивает красным

Comment: @Ксения: а так `if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.VK_F1)) {`  ?

Comment: ` root.setOnKeyPressed(ke -> {
            if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.F1))
                System.out.println("f1");
            //тут должен быть запуск справки
        });`

Comment: вот так работает, похоже в новой яве упразднили VK_

Comment: @Ксения: если я помог вам, мне подправить ответ?

Comment: @Ксения: `VK_F1` [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_F1), `F1` [KeyCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#F1)